# Safari 7.0 Very Slow since move to Mavericks?

Tags: macos, safari, upgrade

Since Upgrading to Mavericks Safari 7.0 is extremely slow. Pages are slow to load, and there is a district Lag when typing into an internet page, you end up typing on the keyboard well ahead of whats actually appearing on the screen?

I use highlight and drag and copy paste within a web browser for work and this has become almost impossible to do without getting extremely frustrated in its low response time?

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a simple solution with reference to a plug-in or feature after upgrade?

After getting to really like Safari I am looking at moving to Firefox or Chrome after this update has rendered it useless and frustrating!

Comment: Are you using any extensions? A good first step would be to turn them off and see if that impacts the performance at all. My experience (and pretty much all others I've read) has been that Safari 7 is a big performance improvement, so it's odd that you're finding the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have helped me a lot.  Its still too early to say for sure, but initial results are very promising.  Just to be clear what I did, I have attached a screen grab...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also, try to clean all sites' data in Safari's settings (web & Flash caches, cookies (maybe)), and restart it. There is "Reset Safari" option, also. Tough, I've never been use it.

Answer (score 0):

Several users are reporting this in Mavericks’ Safari.

[Some “feature” like “Fast Start” may be at play. You can disable it.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107660/how-to-disable-faststart-in-safari)

You may cut the network — unplug the Ethernet cable, or turn off AirPort. It may help you to diagnose the problem and to circumvent it.

You may also turn off JavaScript and see whether that helps.

Another thing to try : disable plug-ins, especially Flash.