# How to disable “Fast Start” in Safari?

Tags: safari, macos, preferences

In Mavericks’ Safari, the “feature” named “Fast Start” begins to load the first result of the search typed in the search bar.

How can I disable such folly ?

Comment: I have received a message about an answer : “There is no such option in Safari even in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist/.” But I see no such answer here. In fact, I prefer @Matthieu’s answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to Safari → Preferences (or hit <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>).
2. Go to *Privacy* and click on the **Do not preload Top Hit in the background** option.

Comment: Nice ! :-) Happily Apple has placed a switch.